# An isogeny from a split algebraic torus

Tags: algebraic-geometry, number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Suppose that there is an isogeny (in the category of commutative algebraic groups) from a split algebraic torus to a semi-abelian variety. Does     it follows that this semi-abelian variety is also an algebraic torus?

Comment: Should be true. Any map $\mathbb{G}_m\to A$ for $A$ an abelian variety has to be constant. Over a perfect field, there is the Chevalley decomposition $T\to G\to A$ for $T$ some torus and $A$ an abelian variety - and the previous statement says that composing the isogeny with $G\to A$ is trivial. Isogenies pull back along all sorts of maps, so as to reduce to the perfect field case.

Comment: More simply, a finite subgroup of a torus is of multiplicative type, the quotient is necessarily a torus.